# I can not add physical device to Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[Physical device option is not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NFJI.png)

i'm trying to connect my device but there is no option appear

Comment: Physical devices don't show up in the "Virtual Devices" dialog that your screen capture shows. They'll show up in the dropdown menu next to the green "play button". On the first connection attempt there should be a dialog on the device asking if you want to let the computer access the device. That needs to be accepted. You might also be missing the [USB driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb).

Answer (score 1):

Please enable developer option in your device.

Step to enable developer option.

1. Open Setting app in device.
2. Search **"Build number"** & tap until message come "You are developer now".
3. Move back to Setting & search **"Developer options"** & tap on it.
4. In Developer option make toggle ON & also make **"USB debugging"** **ON**.

That's it!!

Comment: i have done this but still same problem

Comment: Can you please try by changing your cable ?

Comment: same problem, the device is connected, but the window of adding ohysical device in android studio does not

Answer (score 0):

check if android sdk is installed on your system. You need to enable debugging in your phone settings (Android) After , connect your phone via USB to your machine. you will be asked to give access, you validate on your phone.

Comment: which Sdk ? because i think t is the problem

Comment: i have download google usb driver sdk

Comment: what SDK platform and tools i have to install

Comment: What is your operating system

Comment: Windows, android studio 2021.1.1

Comment: I send you the link of a video that can help you

Comment: sorry but where did you send it ?

Comment: Follow this link. It's React native docs toi setup your système
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: where should i write the commands?